# How to add custom command line in .NET 6 api project

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, command-line-interface

Good evening everyone!

I have a .NET 6 api project in which we have a data import from csvs that works in background with a Quartz job. There is a service class (`IImportService`) in which every csv is read from a local folder, then converted in DataTable, for every row of that DataTable a new object of that entity is created (e.g. product.csv, for every row is created an object of type `Product`) and then added to db.

What I need to implement is a way to start that Import method with **command line**, but I don't understand how to do it. I've read about adding a console app project to the same solution and add main project's namespaces so that I have everything I need to create a CLI command that start `Import` method. Or I've read about the fact that a .NET application already is a CLI application so that I can run the application and do something I haven't quite understand.

The thing is that these solutions seem too complicated to me considering the simplicity of the request, so I was wondering if I was actually missing out on a much simpler solution.

Hoping you can help me understand more about it!

Comment: Just so I understand... You have a web application running on a server somewhere.  And you also want to have a console application on that same server?  Users who are on that server as a workstation could then invoke that console app, or perhaps the web app could also invoke it, etc.?  What stops you from doing that?  Why can't you add a console application project to your solution, implement the functionality you want in that console app, and deploy it to that server?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not that clear, I'm a super junior dev who's been left alone on an api project, I have no tutor, just internet to help me understand things ahahahhaahha
I was just asking for a good solution to solve my problem! Read about other people opinions and learn. I don't know if adding a console app to my solution is a good idea or not

Comment: Well, if you're looking to create a console application then I guess one solution would be to... create a console application.  I'm *assuming* the source code for the web application is as a .Net project in a .Net solution, is that correct?  You can add other projects to that same solution, such as a console application project.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use System.Diagnostics in an API project to do this:

```
    public static void RunCommand(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = new();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
RunCommand("sc create LyklakippanService binpath=\"C:\\Program Files\\Prod\\Lyklakippan\\LyklakippanService.exe\" start=auto");
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Can you explain more specifically what that code does?

Comment: @Ikinidae: This answer is showing how to *invoke* a console application from code.  Are you looking to *create* a console application, or simply *run* an existing one from the API project?  I'd thought it was the former...

Comment: oh okay sorry didn't understand since my question was not how to call a console application in the same solution but how to create a custom command line that call my import method. Thank you!